# Azure DevOps - Automatically create PR after another PR is completed

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Let's say I want to use a Gitflow branching model, so I have 2 long term branches:

- Develop (the name should be enough)
- Master (production)

In case of hotfix in production I will create a branch from master :

- Develop (the name should be enough)
- Master (production)
- Hotfix/my-super-hotfix

According to Gitflow when it's finished we have to merge it to Master and Develop.

But we are using Azure DevOps and the pull request mechanism so we have to create 2 PR (one for Develop and one for Master). Obviously it has been forgotten a lot so we got some inconsistencies...

I don't want the full Gitflow mechanism, I just would like to have a mechanism creating a PR to Develop if a PR to Master has been **completed** only.

Is there a way to achieve that in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Create Pull Request task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest) that creates a PR automatically via build pipeline.

So, create a build that create the PR from hotfix to Develop and configure him to run in CI mode - when the Master is updated. you just need to think how you get the hotfix branch name dynamically (a small script probably).

Comment: We share the same CI for all our branch. Is there a way to say this task should only occurs if we are on master? I see it's possible with the yaml format but we are not using it yet.

Comment: You can use custom condition to say this task to run only if the branch is master: `and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: I didn't see the "classic" tab... Thank you ! :-)